# Sql query in .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to execute a SQL query using entity framework

```
        var timetable = db.Services.SqlQuery("SELECT Services.Date, Services.Time, Trains.Name, ServiceTypes.Name FROM Services INNER JOIN Trains ON Services.TrainId = Trains.Id INNER JOIN ServiceTypes ON Services.ServiceType = ServiceTypes.Id").ToList();
```

that returns the data fine when executing SQL on the database so i know the query works and returns the correct data. However when executing the above line of code i get the following error.

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'MyDataModel.Service'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a
>   corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Following are my data models that i am accessing.

Service Model

```
public partial class Service
{
    public Service()
    {
        this.Tickets = new HashSet<Ticket>();
        this.TrainStops = new HashSet<ServiceStop>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TrainId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DisabledUserId { get; set; }
    public System.TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int ServiceType { get; set; }

    public virtual Train Train { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public virtual ServiceType ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ServiceStop> TrainStops { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

}

Train Model

```
    public partial class Train
{
    public Train()
    {
        this.Services = new HashSet<Service>();
        this.Tickets = new HashSet<Ticket>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Seats { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

}

ServiceType Model

```
    public partial class ServiceType
{
    public ServiceType()
    {
        this.Services = new HashSet<Service>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query result needs to map to `Service`, completely. So modify your `SELECT` to include all of the `Service` columns.

Comment: Thanks it works by why does .net require to map to it completely ?? when normaly this is not required.?

Comment: It is your ORM that requires it. In your case, Entity Framework (i think). The DbSet (which is your `db.Services`) requires that the result columns map to each property of your `Service` class. If one or the other is missing, your ORM will throw an exception. Alternatively, you could have created a separate class to represent the results of your original query... for example `db.Database.SqlQuery<YourCustomClass>("...")`. The class `YourCustomClass` would not have to be a table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the ID column from your Services table. Try adding it in the SQL string.

Comment: When adding that i still get the same error but for TrainId and DisabledId but those are columns that i do not require to be selected.